# Need help writing a Powershell script to automate a silent install of Avamar Client on multiple machines

Tags: script, powershell

I am writing a Powershell script to automate a silent install of Avamar Client on multiple machines.

Here is the script that I have written so far, but it keeps coming up with errors:

```
#Variables
$computername=Get-Content C:PSdeploy\list.txt
$sourcefile= "\\mydomain.org\public\AvamarClient-windows-x86_64-7.1.100-370.msi"
$credentials = Get-Credential
#This section will install the software
foreach ($computer in $computername)
{
    $destinationFolder = "\\$computer\C$\Temp"
    #This section will copy the $sourcefile to the $destinationFolder. If the Folder does not exist it will create it.
    if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))
    {
        New-Item $destinationfolder -Type Directory
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process 'c:\temp\AvamarClient-windows-x86_64-7.1.100-370.msi' -ArgumentList msiexec /I} -credential $creds
}
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
PS C:\Users\n1254937> C:\Users\myuserid\Desktop\AvamarClient remote install.ps1
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/I'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
    + PSComputerName        : test.mydomain.org
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [definition for `-ArgumentList`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) is `<String[]>`, which is an *array of strings*.

As-is, it's seeing it as `-ArgumentList msiexec`, followed by `/I` which isn't a valid argument for `Start-Process`.

To specify multiple arguments you need to provide them as an array of strings, which can be written as a comma-separated list in PowerShell.  So to specify your two arguments you'd use `-ArgumentList 'msiexec','/I'`.

Having said that, I don't believe it will work even if you make that correction.  As-is, you're telling it to run the .MSI file, and feeding the .MSI file two arguments: `msiexec` and `/I`.

What you should be aiming to do is start `msiexec`, specifying the .MSI file and the `/I` as arguments for `msiexec`.

So try something like:

```
{Start-Process 'msiexec' -ArgumentList 'c:\temp\AvamarClient-windows-x86_64-7.1.100-370.msi','/I'}
```

Or just:

```
{Start-Process 'msiexec' 'c:\temp\AvamarClient-windows-x86_64-7.1.100-370.msi','/I'}
```

...since `-ArgumentList` is actually optional (like `-FilePath` is).